# Virtual class and inheritance in c++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I am developing a new project using c++:

**File A.cpp**

```
#ifndef A_hpp
#define A_hpp

class A{

public:
    A(int at, int bt);
    ~A();
    virtual double b()=0;
    virtual double c()=0;
    virtual double g()=0;
private:
    int at;
    int bt;
};

#endif /* A_hpp */
```

**File A.cpp**

```
#include "A.hpp"

A::A(int at, int bt){
    this->at=at;
    this->bt=bt;
}

A::~A(){
    //no code
}
```

**File B.hpp**

```
#ifndef B_hpp
#define B_hpp

#include "A.hpp"
class B:public A{

public:
    B(int at, int bt, double val);
    ~B();

private:
    double *elems;
};
#endif /* B_hpp */
```

**File B.cpp**

```
#include "B.hpp"
#include "A.hpp"

B::B(int at, int bt, double val):A(at, bt){

    elems=new double[at*bt];

    for(int i=0;i<at*bt;i++)
        *(elems+i)=val;
}
B::~B(){
    delete []elems;
}

double A::c(){
        return *elem;
    }

double A::b(){
        return (*elem)-*(elem+1);
    }


double A::g(){
        return (*elem)*(*elem)*(*elem);
    }
```

I get an error, *Use of undeclared identifier 'elem'*, when I implement these virtual function b(), c() et g() in the class B

Comment: Please copy-paste the error message, instead of trying to paraphrase it. EDIT: the lack of indentation and spacing made your code **very** hard to read. You are implementing `a`, `b`, `c` functions for your `A` class (`double A::b()`), and `A` class knows nothing about `elems`. Did you want to implement them for `B` class (`double B::b()`)?

Comment: Indentation, please!

Comment: Why you define A's member functions `b, c, g` in source of `B.cpp`?

Comment: More to the point, why do you bother defining `A`'s member functions `b, c, g` at all? You declared them as abstract. Also, you _should know_ that `A`'s member functions will not have access to members declared in `B`.... It does not matter what file you declare them in!

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, I edit my code.

Comment: @Raindrop7, I edit my code

Comment: @CraigYoung, I edit my code

Comment: If you write `double A::c(){ ...`,  you do not implement `c` in class `B` but rather `c` in class `A`; and class `A` is not aware of `elem`, which is a member of `B`, right?

Comment: @BetterEnglish All of these unnecessary pointers and `new`/`delete` mess. Use idiomatic c++ constructs please!

Comment: Replace the `new[]` stuff with `std::vector` and add a virtual destructor in the base class. These two things must be repaired in the code before proceeding with any further problems. Also consider making the public functions non-virtual and make them delegate to private virtual functions instead.

Comment: @BetterEnglish The way you've changed your code between edits suggests you're not copy-pasting from your local source code. Don't do that! You just create confusion when you inevitably make a hash job of it - _especially as you're very obviously not familiar with the nuances of the language. You make your own task more difficult and waste everyone's time when you don't do things properly.

Comment: @CraigYoung, Sorry for the confusion but i have used the same code with some correction of typo. That 's it!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, What do you mean by idiomatic c++ constructs!

Comment: @BetterEnglish You miss the point. You wouldn't have to correct typo's if you simply copy-paste.

Comment: @BetterEnglish _"What do you mean by idiomatic c++ constructs!"_ Standard [container classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), [smart ponters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are implementing the overrides for the base classes virtual functions incorrectly.

What your code is actually doing is implementing the pure virtual functions from `A` while trying to use the class member variables from `B`

Given your base class:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int at, int bt);
    ~A();
    virtual double b()=0;
    virtual double c()=0;
    virtual double g()=0;
private:
    int at;
    int bt;
};
```

Your child class should be:

```
class B:public A
{
public:
    B(int at, int bt, double val);
    ~B();
    virtual double b();
    virtual double c();
    virtual double g();
private:
    double *elem;
};
```

With the implementation of `B` like so:

```
B::B(int at, int bt, double val):A(at, bt)
{
    elem=new double[at*bt];
    for(int i=0;i<at*bt;i++)
    {
        *(elem+i)=val;
    }
}
double B::a()
{
    return *elem;
}
B::~B()
{
    delete []elem;
}
double B::b()
{
    return (*elem)-*(elem+1);
}

double B::g()
{
    return (*elem)*(*elem)*(*elem);
}
```

Comment: This does not address the original problem being the assumed typo of `elem` instead of `elems`.

Comment: Also making `b, c, g` pure virtual functions will make class B ADT thus you cannot instantiate it.

Comment: @Raindrop7 My bad, that was a Copy paste Slip up. will fix

Comment: @Gambit Never mind, on second thoughts I actually have no idea what OP intends. Question seems all over the place.

Comment: @CraigYoung A misunderstanding from all parties it seems.

Comment: I think it comes down to a combination of typos in the question and a lack of understanding as far as inheritance, polymorphism and virtual functions goes.

Comment: @AlexZywicki, I agree with you, I lack some fundamental c++ inheritance and virtual function. I am more comfortable with java.

Comment: See this list of books on C++: http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1865694

Comment: @BetterEnglish Regardless, that's still not an excuse to not copy-paste a simple example of your problem code to ask your question.

Comment: @AlexZywicki, thanks so much for your constructive advice!

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo. Change `elem` to `elems`.

Plus,

To imlement virtual inheritace you have to add the methods in the class `B` header:

```
virtual double b();
virtual double c();
virtual double g();
```

And in the implementation change namespace `A` by `B` in the .cpp:

```
double B::c(){
        return *elems;
    }
double B::b(){
        return (*elems)-*(elems+1);
    }
double B::g(){
        return (*elems)*(*elems)*(*elems);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you misinterpret placing an implementation in a particular `B.cpp`-file as "implementing something in class B". If you write `double A::c(){ ...`, you do not implement `c` in class `B` but rather `c` in class `A`, regardless in which file you write this implementation. And class `A` is not aware of `elems`, which is a member of `B`, what explains the error message `Use of undeclared identifier 'elem'`.

Write `double B::c(){ ...` instead, and also declare `double c()` in the definition of class `B`. (The same of course for the other functions)

Answer (score 0):

`elems` is a member of class B which derived from class A so you cannot access the members of a child from the parent:

```
double A::b(){ 
    return (*elems)-*(elems+1); // elems is a member of B not A
}
```